# C# How can I resolve the type dynamically using some DI container?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I have two *versions* of parameter types to pass to the server, I prefer to keep both versions and resolve it automatically using unity container (since it part of the project design), and for most of the code is identical for both versions.

In my config file, I have a property `Version`, which can be some value like `1.0`, `1.2` etc. I want to resolve `service` based on this value.

Here is my mock code in a different way to illustrate my problem.

[image]

```
using System;

namespace Versions
{
    public interface IService<in T> where T : IObj
    {
        void DoSomething1(T obj);
        void DoSomething2(T obj);
        void DoSomething3(int id);
    }

    public abstract class ServiceBase<T> : IService<T> where T : IObj
    {
        public abstract void DoSomething1(T obj);

        public abstract void DoSomething2(T obj);

        public virtual void DoSomething3(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    }

    public class Service1<T> : ServiceBase<T> where T : IObj1
    {
        public override void DoSomething1(T obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void DoSomething2(T obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Service2<T> : ServiceBase<T> where T : IObj2
    {
        public override void DoSomething1(T obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void DoSomething2(T obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface IObj
    {
    }

    public interface IObj1 : IObj
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IObj2 : IObj
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Age { get; set; }
        DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    }

    public class Obj1 : IObj1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Obj2 : IObj2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        // e.g.: v1.0, v1.2
        private static readonly string Version = "v1.0"; // ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["version"];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeContainer container = new SomeContainer();

            var service = container.Resolve(Version);


        }
    }

    public class SomeContainer
    {
        public IService<IObj> Resolve(string version)
        {
            if (version == "v1.0")
            {
                return new Service1<Obj1>();
            }

            if (version == "v1.2")
            {
                return new Service2<Obj2>();
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException("version not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with a contravariant interface, it would only work if your interface was covariant, i.e. `IService<out T>` which is not possible here.